# How to hide launcher from desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am very new to ubuntu and want to hide the launcher from the desktop. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should click right on the desktop, select change wallpaper(or similar, i have it in another language). After that pass to secondo curtain, called "behavior"(or similar) and turn on the auto hide of the launcher.